# magento 2 : How to render background images in css pages

Tags: magento2, css

How do you render a background image on a css page.

i.e

```
#account-links--point {

  background-image: url(/images/pop-up-box-point.svg); 

}
```

i realise that for a less you can do this:

```
@{baseDir}images/home-slider/slide-1.jpg
```

but my css does not use less.The url for my css is:

```
\app\design\frontend\myTheme\Theme-frontend-default\web\css\local-m.css
```

the images are stored in my theme folder;

```
\app\design\frontend\Mytheme\Theme-frontend-default\web\images
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with images and css to use image as background image.

So the answer is:

```
#account-links--point {
  background-image: url('../images/myimage.png');
}
```

"**..**" will tell browser to go back to parent directory that is **web** directory and look inside **images** directory for the image file.

This is valid way because if you have development, staging and production website then you don't have to change the domain name everywhere.

Comment: Happy to help you :-)

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work when you deploy static content (or just let the server try to find it in developer mode). For background images defined in CSS I have to use the grunt scripts to push them to the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might not answer your question in full but how about changing the image directory to `pub/media/theme_images` and using:

```
#account-links--point {

  background-image: url('www.mydomain.com/media/theme_images/myimage.png'); 

}
```